# Is there a good, free WYSIWYG editor for creating HTML using a Django template?

Tags: html, django

I'm interested to get a free, WYSIWYG HTML editor that is compatible with Django template. Any ideas?

> Thanks LainMH.
>
> But I afraid fckeditor is used in web app, for the purpose of editing
>   HTML. What I want is an editor that allows me to write HTML that is
>   Django compatible.
>
> Hope this clarifies the issue.

Answer (score 5):

http://www.fckeditor.net/ ?

EDIT: Just found this: http://blog.newt.cz/blog/integration-fckeditor-django/

Answer (score 3):

vim has syntax highlighting for Django template tags, works for me ^_^

Answer (score 2):

I don't think any of the HTML based editors will work with the django templates, but rather the editable content areas within templates.

The process for creating / editing Django templates is really to create a standard HTML page first (with CSS & images etc), then make that into a base template. Then you create other templates that extend the base one.

The type or program typically used for editing the templates would be an IDE, although I prefer the lighter weight [Textmate  bundle](http://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/TextMate) for editing the templates (and Django python code). If you have an IDE, just google for a Python pluggin for Django.

What will probably help most is having the [Django templates page](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/templates/) open, or using a [Django cheetsheet](http://www.mercurytide.co.uk/whitepapers/django-cheat-sheet/).

Answer (score 1):

According to brief Googling (no personal experience with this), Aptana now supports Python development via Pydev. Pydev again can be configured to work with Django.

Thus I would expect Aptana to be usable with Django templates aswell, though I have no complete guide these links should be helpful :

- http://www.aptana.com/python
- http://pydev.blogspot.com/2006/09/configuring-pydev-to-work-with-django.html

Hope this helps.